# Running Cassandra as a service on OpenSuse

Tags: installation, cassandra, package, opensuse, startupscript

I am trying to run Cassandra as a service on OpenSuse (Leap 42.1).

I have tried installing with apache-cassandra-2.1.11-bin.tar.gz and then copying /etc/init.d/cassandra from https://gist.github.com/sgomezvillamor/5458309. However, the startup script is not designed for OpenSuse, as the system.log says:

/etc/init.d/cassandra: line 30: daemon: command not found.

The problem would not exist if there would be an installer that would create the scripts correctly, similarly as there are for some other OSs. Searching for an installation package, I found http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/announcing-rpms-cassandra and tried to look for an rpm in rpm.riptano.com but I cannot figure out which one would work in OpenSuse.

Which of those packages would work for OpenSuse? Or, how should I modify the startup script for Suse-fying it?

Answer (score 0):

I would check these instructions which are for Cassandra 2.1: [Installing DataStax Community 2.1 on RHEL-based systems](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/install/installRHEL_t.html).

I'm not sure whether that will get you 100% there on an OpenSUSE system, but should get you very close.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with /etc/init.d/cassandra file:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# /etc/init.d/cassandra
#
# Startup script for Cassandra
# 
# chkconfig: 2345 20 80
# description: Starts and stops Cassandra

#. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

export CASSANDRA_HOME=/opt/apache-cassandra-2.1.11
export CASSANDRA_CONF=$CASSANDRA_HOME/conf
export CASSANDRA_INCLUDE=$CASSANDRA_HOME/bin/cassandra.in.sh
#export CASSANDRA_OWNR=cassandra
export CASSANDRA_OWNR=root
#NAME="cassandra"
NAME="root"
log_file=/srv/cassandra/log/cassandra.log
pid_file=/var/run/cassandra/cassandra.pid
lock_file=/var/lock/subsys/$NAME
CASSANDRA_PROG=/opt/apache-cassandra-2.1.11/bin/cassandra

# The first existing directory is used for JAVA_HOME if needed.
JVM_SEARCH_DIRS="/usr/lib/jvm/jre /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.* /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.*/jre"

# Read configuration variable file if it is present
[ -r /etc/default/$NAME ] && . /etc/default/$NAME

# If JAVA_HOME has not been set, try to determine it.
if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ]; then
    # If java is in PATH, use a JAVA_HOME that corresponds to that. This is
    # both consistent with how the upstream startup script works, and with
    # the use of alternatives to set a system JVM (as is done on Debian and
    # Red Hat derivatives).
    java="`/usr/bin/which java 2>/dev/null`"
    if [ -n "$java" ]; then
        java=`readlink --canonicalize "$java"`
        JAVA_HOME=`dirname "\`dirname \$java\`"`
    else
        # No JAVA_HOME set and no java found in PATH; search for a JVM.
        for jdir in $JVM_SEARCH_DIRS; do
            if [ -x "$jdir/bin/java" ]; then
                JAVA_HOME="$jdir"
                break
            fi
        done
        # if JAVA_HOME is still empty here, punt.
    fi
fi
JAVA="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
export JAVA_HOME JAVA

case "$1" in
    start)
        # Cassandra startup
        echo -n "Starting Cassandra: "
        su $CASSANDRA_OWNR -c "$CASSANDRA_PROG -p $pid_file" > $log_file 2>&1
        retval=$?
        [ $retval -eq 0 ] && touch $lock_file
        echo "OK"
        ;;
    stop)
        # Cassandra shutdown
        echo -n "Shutdown Cassandra: "
        su $CASSANDRA_OWNR -c "kill `cat $pid_file`"
        retval=$?
        [ $retval -eq 0 ] && rm -f $lock_file
        for t in `seq 40`; do $0 status > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0.5 || break; done
        # Adding a sleep here to give jmx time to wind down (CASSANDRA-4483). Not ideal...
        # Adam Holmberg suggests this, but that would break if the jmx port is changed
        # for t in `seq 40`; do netstat -tnlp | grep "0.0.0.0:7199" > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0.1 || break; done
        sleep 5
        STATUS=`$0 status`
        if [[ $STATUS == "$NAME is stopped" ]]; then
            echo "OK"
        else
            echo "ERROR: could not stop $NAME:  $STATUS"
            exit 1
        fi
        ;;
    reload|restart)
        $0 stop
        $0 start
        ;;
    status)
        status -p $pid_file cassandra
        exit $?
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: `basename $0` start|stop|status|restart|reload"
        exit 1
esac

exit 0
```